# On an initiative roll in Cyberpunk Red, can you roll a critical success or a critical failure?

Tags: initiative, cyberpunk-red

On an initiative roll in Cyberpunk Red, can you roll a critical success or a critical failure?

The Cyberpunk Red Jumpstart Kit rules read, "When you roll a natural roll of 10 on your d10, you've scored a Critical Success" (20), but this is in the context of "Resolving Actions with Skills" - which may be a different context from an initiative roll.

For initiative, the rules merely say, "When a combat starts, everyone rolls Initiative: Initiative = REF + 1d10" (24), and they make no mention of the possibility of a critical success or a critical failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can roll a Critical Success or Critical Failure on an Initiative Roll.

Here is a [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://rtalsoriangames.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RTG-CPR-CoreBookFAQv1.3.pdf) link to the official FAQ as of July 28th, 2021. There is a table on page 2 that specifies which modifiers apply to which rolls.